# How to get PHP date time to use that of the server?

Tags: php, php.ini, timezone

My PHP scripts are currently an hour out due to BST being in operation (GMT+1).

Is there a way of setting php.ini's date.timezone to keep the time correct for BST/DST, without having to manually modify it when the clocks go back?

Alternatively, if PHP used the server's time, which is correct, that would work. Is there a way to tell it to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming reasonably-recent PHP, if you define date.timezone correctly via date_default_timezone_set(), PHP will handle the GMT offsets itself.  Assuming, on the other hand, that you're stuck with old PHP, you'll have to do one of three things:

- bite the bullet and upgrade PHP
- bite the bullet and implement your TZ mechanics yourself (**not** recommended, but see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for several examples in various shades of godawful), or
- start doing heretical things like system('date') in your code.

Of those, the clear winning solution is a PHP upgrade.  How old is your version, really?

Comment: I'm running PHP Version 5.2.10, is that recent enough? I can upgrade, but presumably if 5.2.10 is new enough for the offset functionality to be in place then there's something else amiss?

Comment: 5.2.10 was released June 18, 2009.  Have there been BST changes since then?  I'm not in the UK, so I wouldn't know.  The TZ data is "baked into" PHP, though; it doesn't use /etc/tzdata or equivalent.  5.2.13 is the most recent 5.2 version, if you're concerned about E_DEPRECATED and some of the other changes in 5.3; otherwise, 5.3.2 will be your winner.